# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't boot anymore after python uninstall

Tags: boot, apt, python, 20.04, crash

so as title says, I cannot boot anymore after I removed python. I had anaconda before and certain packages didnt work anymore so I wanted to remove python and anaconda both to reinstall python fresh.

However, I wasnt very successful. After removing python the terminal from the left window disappeared aswell and I couldn't open terminals anymore and if I wanted to log in, it didnt work.

After rebooting, I didn't get into the GUI, but only had that tty terminal.

These are pictures from boot. Can I still save my ubuntu version? Or if not, can I still save the data on it?

I meanwhile managed to access my files via paragon linux software from windows. At the moment I try to copy my original ubuntu files completely, but even only "finding" the files takes hours.

So could I try to copy certain files into my ubuntu drive and then install them from tty terminal for example?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you can login to a tty: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I think I tried it, but didn't work from what I remember. After copying the data, I will try and report. Thanks already!

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you must post a clear, readable picture of the complete output. You may not understand those details, but we do and they are critical to helping you.

Comment: thank you, so I will get back once its copied with a detailed photo from the output.

Comment: I tried sudo apt install ubuntu- desktop and it worked whooooaaaa. But I got a crash report for Package: python 3 3.8.2-Oubuntu2. So I am in normal desktop and all appears normal more or less. terminal on the left in bar is also visible again.

Comment: should I after sudo apt install ubuntu desktop install more packages and so on?

Comment: The `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package should pull in everything that was originally installed by the Ubuntu installer. After that, it's up to you. It's not magical, and it's not a complete system restore - it only reinstalls packages that you removed. It doesn't fix anything you that you may have broken some other way: It might not restore links or fix config files or recover data.